# JOptionPane Yes or No window

Tags: java, swing, return-value, joptionpane

I am trying to create a message with a Yes or No button.  Then a window will appear with a certain message that depends on if the user clicked Yes or No.

Here is my code:

```
public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        //default icon, custom title
        int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
            null,
            "Would you like green eggs and ham?",
            "An Inane Question",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

        if(true){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "HELLO");
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "GOODBYE");
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Right now it prints HELLO whether or not you press Yes or No.  How do I get it to show GOODBYE when the user chooses No?

Comment: You have dead code in this. You else part will never gonna execute.

Comment: 10 upvotes and 7 times a favorite question... I am wondering why

Answer (score 80):

"if(true)" will always be true and it will never make it to the else. If you want it to work correctly you have to do this:

```java
int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, title, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "HELLO");
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "GOODBYE");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: @JoshKing If it worked for you, then you should upvote and accept this answer.

Answer (score 8):

You are always checking for a true condition, hence your message will always show.

You should replace your `if (true)` statement with `if ( n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)`

> When one of the showXxxDialog methods returns an integer, the possible
>   values are:
>
> YES_OPTION NO_OPTION CANCEL_OPTION OK_OPTION CLOSED_OPTION

From [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#field_summary)

Comment: +1 for linking to the JavaDocs, but I updated the link from 1.4.2 to 1.7, and added an anchor to the field summary.

Answer (score 4):

You can fix it with this:

```
if(n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "HELLO");
}
else
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "GOODBYE");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Code for Yes and No Message

```
      int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(  
                null,
                "sample question?!" ,
                "",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

      if(n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
      {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Opening...");
      }
      else
      {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Goodbye");
          System.exit(0);
```

Comment: There should be a closing curly bracket at the end for the ones that  copy-pasted :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this a whole simpler:

```
int test = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like green eggs and ham?", "An insane question!");
switch(test) {
    case 0: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "HELLO!"); //Yes option
    case 1: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "GOODBYE!"); //No option
    case 2: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "GOODBYE!"); //Cancel option
}
```

Comment: You miss break statement in your switch.

Answer (score 2):

You are writing `if(true)` so it will always show "Hello " message.

You should take decision on the basis of value of `n` returned.

Comment: Yes but How would I code it? I could assign the output to a variable but I do not know how to do this

Comment: @JoshKing I don't remeber the values exactly. Try printing value of n on the console and check what it gives when yes is pressed and what when no is pressed. Then use if(n == ?) else

Comment: *".. Then use if(n == ?)"*  Don't use 'magic values'.  The defined constants will work next JRE, next year..

Answer (score 1):

For better understand how it works!

```
int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Yes No Cancel", "YesNoCancel", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
    if(n == 0)
        {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "You pressed YES\n"+"Pressed value is = "+n);
        }
    else if(n == 1)
        {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "You pressed NO\n"+"Pressed value is = "+n);
        }
    else if (n == 2)
        {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "You pressed CANCEL\n"+"Pressed value is = "+n);
        }
    else if (n == -1)
        {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "You pressed X\n"+"Pressed value is = "+n);
        }
```

OR

```
int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Yes No Cancel", "YesNoCancel", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
    switch (n) {
        case 0:
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "You pressed YES\n"+"Pressed value is = "+n);
            break;
        case 1:
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "You pressed NO\n"+"Pressed value is = "+n);
            break;
        case 2:
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "You pressed CANCEL\n"+"Pressed value is = "+n);
            break;
        case -1:
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "You pressed X\n"+"Pressed value is = "+n);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines ....

```
   //default icon, custom title
int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Would you like green eggs and ham?","An Inane Question",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

String result = "?";
switch (n) {
case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
  result = "YES";
  break;
case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
  result = "NO";
  break;
default:
  ;
}
System.out.println("Replace? " + result);
```

you may also want to look at [DialogDemo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#DialogDemo)

Comment: You have written `case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:` 2 times.