# Return to method & passing variables between methods?

Tags: java, methods, return

I'm currently doing an assignment regarding an ATM machine that I have to program. There are 4 methods in total - MAIN, WITHDRAWAL, DEPOSIT and CHECKBALANCE. From the MAIN method, I have a menu and therefore would be sending variables to the rest of the methods from there.

I would like to know if there is a way, if after I finish calculating my total in WITHDRAWAL, that I can pass that value to CHECKBALANCE? Because I have tried:

```
total = deposit - withdrawal;
checkbalance(withdrawal);
```

For the user to check their balance, they have to get the value calculated in their previous choice sent to the CHECKBALANCE method right? But the error that popped up was "arguements list differ in length". Also, I would like to know how to return back to the menu in MAIN after I finish each task performed in the other methods. I have tried:

```
choice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to return to the    menu? (1 = Yes, 2 = No));

if (choice == 2)
{
System.exit(0);
}

main();
```

I would appreciate it VERY much if any one of you could lend me a helping hand. I'm still new in this and just started learning java this semester. Please and thank you to everybody :)

**UPDATES:**

```
package lab2;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class LAB2 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        double initialAmount, withdraw = 0, deposit = 0, checkBalance = 0;
        int choice;

        initialAmount = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter current savings amount: "));

        while(initialAmount < 0)
        {
            initialAmount = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid amount. Amount cannot be negative. Please re-enter" ));   
        }

        choice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("MENU: "
                + "What would you like to do? Please choose from 1 - 4\n"
                + "1) Withdraw\n"
                + "2) Deposit\n"
                + "3) Check balance\n"
                + "4) Exit"));
        while ((choice <= 0) || (choice > 4))
        {
            choice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid option. Please choose between option 1 - 4: "));
        }

        if (choice == 1)
        {
            ChoiceOne(withdraw, initialAmount);
        }

        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            ChoiceTwo(deposit, initialAmount);
        }
        else if (choice == 3)
        {
            ChoiceThree(checkBalance, initialAmount);
        }

        else if (choice == 4)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static void ChoiceOne(double withdraw, double initialAmount)
    {
        double afterDeduction;
        int input, choice1;

        withdraw = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Your current balance is: RM"+initialAmount+" . How much would you like to withdraw? "));

        while (withdraw > initialAmount)
        {
            input = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insufficient balance to perform withdrawal. Continue? (1 = Yes, 2 = Exit ")); 

            if (input == 2)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you!");
                System.exit(0);
            }  
            else if (input == 1)
            {
                withdraw = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Your current balance is: RM"+initialAmount+" . How much would you like to withdraw? "));

                afterDeduction = initialAmount - withdraw;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have withdrawn RM"+withdraw+". Your total balanace now is: RM"+afterDeduction+".");

                choice1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to continue to menu or exit? (1 = Yes /2 = No"));

                if (choice1 == 2)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }

                if (choice1 == 1)
                {

                }
            }
        }

        while  (withdraw < 0)
        {
            input = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid withdrawal. Please re-enter: "));
        }

        afterDeduction = initialAmount - withdraw;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You have withdrawn RM"+withdraw+". Your total balanace now is: RM"+afterDeduction+"."
                + "/nWould you like to return to the menu? ");
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static void ChoiceTwo (double deposit, double initialAmount)
    {
        double afterAddition; 
        int input;

        deposit = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much would you like to deposit? "));

        while (deposit < 0)
        {
            input = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid deposit. Please re-enter: "));
        }

        if (deposit > 0)
        {
        afterAddition = deposit + initialAmount;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You have deposit RM"+deposit+". Your total balanace now is: RM"+afterAddition+"."
                + "/nWould you like to return to the menu? ");
        }
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static void ChoiceThree (double CheckBalance, double initialAmount)
    {
    }

}
```

Comment: Post here your checkbalance and withdrawal methods

Comment: You can use yes/no visual prompt instead of entering number: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396870/joptionpane-yes-or-no-window

Comment: @Niemand I have updated it with the full codings~

Comment: @kajacx thanks for the suggestion! i will use that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create new object, let's call it SessionData and store all operation data in it. It could significantly simplify argument passing issues. That's all I can advise basing on information provided by you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you have done looking at just a small section of the code, however, you could try using boolean values to check if the user wants to return to the main menu if the boolean value is equal to true then show the main menu if it's equal to false then the program moves on/ends.

Comment: I have updated the question with the full codes for your better understanding. Thank you very much :)